# How to skip whole step if file do not exist for that item reader or step

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

ISSUE:> I am having item reader writer processor for my spring batch job. And when I am running it, it is giving me error Failed to initialize the reader and
also showing :>
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): file

**My requirement is**: I want my item reader to not run if file does not exists.

Can anyone help me: I want to skip whole step if file do not exist for that item reader.
My step consist of (item reader, processor and writer).

Just tell me how to skip step, if file do not exist. Any help will be appreciated.And is there anyway to set reader to non strict mode.

Comment: Why even bother starting the job if there is nothing to process?

Comment: I am having three more step. and I dont want other step to fail due to my first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#configuringSkip): You can set skip condition (and limit) on a "chunk/step".

```
@Bean
public Step step1() {
  return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
    .<String, String>chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
    .reader(flatFileItemReader())
    .writer(itemWriter())
    .faultTolerant()
    .skipLimit(0) // 0: dont re-try
    .skip(FlatFileParseException.class) // when you use FlatFileItemWriter,
      // but other exception (type) possible, e.g. IllegalStateException.class
    .build();
}
```

To set "non-strict" mode in FlatFileItemReader, just:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<XY> flatFileItemReader() {

  FlatFileItemReader<XY> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
  //!
  reader.setStrict(false);
  // reader.setXYZ ...
  return reader;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. From 2days I am finding solution so as my step do not fail. your second answer worked for me. Now item reader is not giving error if file is not present. After setting reader.setStrict(false);